# What is the correct return type replacement for JSX.Element after the global JSX namespace has been deprecated?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, react-typescript

In `@types/react`, the global `JSX` namespace [has been deprecated](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/266eae5148c535e6b41fe5d0adb2ad23f302bc8a/types/react/index.d.ts#L3182):

```
declare global {
    /**
     * @deprecated Use `React.JSX` instead of the global `JSX` namespace.
     */
    namespace JSX {
    ...
    }
}
```

Since I have ESLint's `deprecation/deprecation` rule (from plugin `eslint-plugin-deprecation`) enabled, I now receive errors for return types of function components like this:

```
export default function TestComponent(): JSX.Element { // This JSX is marked as deprecated
    return (
        <span>Test</span>
    );
}
```

What is the correct return type replacement for `JSX.Element` in this case now that the global `JSX` namespace is deprecated?

Is it `React.JSX.Element` as stated in the deprecation message like this:

```
export default function TestComponent(): React.JSX.Element { ... }
```

Or is it `ReactElement` like this:

```
import { ReactElement } from "react";
export default function TestComponent(): ReactElement { ... }
```

Or is it best to declare the function component using `React.FC` and let TypeScript infer the return type like this:

```
export const TestComponent: React.FC = () => { ... };
```

Comment: Also wonder the same thing, using `React.JSX.Element` seems to work fine, but not sure if this is still the best practice.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use directly `React.ReactElement` (or, to be more precise, `React.ReactElement | null`):

```
import { ReactElement } from "react";

export function TestComponent(): ReactElement | null {
  return (
    Math.random() < 0.5
      ? null
      : <>
          A single Element (could be a Fragment like here)
        </>
  );
}
```

This is exactly what (the no longer recommended) [`React.FC`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/266eae5148c535e6b41fe5d0adb2ad23f302bc8a/types/react/index.d.ts#L544-L552) enforces:

```
interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
  (props: P, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
  // ...
}
```

And it is also the definition of a [`JSXElementConstructor`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/266eae5148c535e6b41fe5d0adb2ad23f302bc8a/types/react/index.d.ts#L78-L79):

```
type JSXElementConstructor<P> =
  | ((props: P) => ReactElement<any, any> | null) // Case of a Function Component
  | (new (props: P) => Component<any, any>); // Case of a Class-based Component
```

---

That being said, unless you have some rule forcing you to type your Function Component return type, you can just omit it for easiness:

```
export function TestComponent() {
  // ...
}
```

Obviously, that function can now return anything, and TypeScript will not complain... except when you try using it as a Function Component in a JSX template, as pointed out in [fb/cra#8177](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177):

> The only benefit I really see to `React.FC` [...] is that it specifies the return type, which catches mistakes [...]
>
> In practice, I think this is fine, as it'll be caught as soon as you try to use it:

```
const Example = () => <Component />; // Error here, due to Component returning the wrong thing
```

Comment: And what about `keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements`?

Comment: @Mir-Ismaili I am not sure what you mean? https://tsplay.dev/WyxdKm

Comment: Why is react FC no longer recommended?  I remember that being the case a few years ago, but it seems to have dropped the assumption of children props.

Comment: @VayneValerius: `React.FC` does not work with extra generics; for more reasons, see [fb/cra#8177](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177) (you are right to point out that it no longer includes `children`).

Answer (score 13):

Use `React.JSX`.

---

Or import `JSX` from `"react"`:

```js
import type {JSX} from 'react'
```

Comment: I think this answer is most straight-forward and correct as docs says `Use React.JSX instead of the global JSX namespace.`

Comment: this removed the warning